# I am trying to use this https://www.amcharts.com/demos/professional-candlesticks/ in nuxt 2

Tags: nuxt.js, amcharts, amcharts5

I have already installed the "@amcharts/amcharts5" npm module as specified in the document, but i keep getting this error

"export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-0!../node_modules/ etc

How do I proceed?

Comment: Hi, mind sharing the `package.json` + `nuxt.config.js` files?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.30",
    "@amcharts/amcharts5": "^5.2.33",
  }  @kissu I haven't added anything related in nuxt.config yet

Comment: Why do you have both the v4 and v5? Also, how are you importing it yourself?

Comment: @kissu i was trying out both to see which one would work...i want to know how to import it properly.

Comment: That one seems to be a good start: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/integrations/vue/#Adding_charts

Comment: alright i've done that, getting "export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-0!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./Chart.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&'  error @kissu

Comment: Be sure to clean your `node_modules` properly. Install them with yarn or PNPM and try again. Also, please share the exact code snippet of what you tried, a [repro] or a public github repo.